# How to read text after a specific character with PHP

Tags: php, scripting

Lately what I've wanted to do is read specific text after a specific character. What I want to do is read the numbers after an equal sign. This is the text that I have:

```
Lime Green = 13,
Sensei Gray = 14,
Aqua = 15,
Arctic White = 16,
Black Sunglasses = 101,
Dark Vision Goggles = 102,
```

The numbers that are after the "=" sign is the ID for the text. What I want to do is grab the ID for the text an place it in the variable $id, any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [explode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$parts = explode(' = ', rtrim($line, ','));
```

Then `$parts[0]` will be the phrase and `$parts[1]` will be the ID.

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expression for this

```
$content="Lime Green = 13,
Sensei Gray = 14,
Aqua = 15,
Arctic White = 16,
Black Sunglasses = 101,
Dark Vision Goggles = 102,";

preg_match_all("/=(.*),/siU",$content,$output);

print_r($output[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Set up an array with the different values/names.
2. Loop through the array.
3. Use explode("=") to split each string around the equals sign.
4. Get the second half of each array (explode returns an array)